# Apply Style to List Items that Contain Nested List

Tags: html, css

I have a list that looks something like:

```
<li>List Item 1</li>
<li>List Item 2
    <ul>
        <li>Sub List Item 1</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>List Item 3</li>
```

I would like to style all list items that contain a nested list as bold and leave the rest of them normal:

- List Item 1
- **List Item 2**

  - Sub List Item 1
- List Item 3

Is this something I can do using CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to manually add a class to your list items with children:

```
<li class="nestedlist">
```

correct? You want it to be automatically detected?

There is no way to change the style of a parent element in CSS based on a child, unfortunately. You could do it with a quick JS, though.

Here's an interesting post about WHY they won't allow us to do it...though I'm not convinced!
http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I thought.  To javascript!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the jQuery .children() function.

Something like this:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if ($(this).children().length > 0){
        $(this).css('font-weight','bold');  
    }
});
```

You'd need to set up your css so that the child li wouldn't be bold as well. Or you could add additional jQuery to prevent it.